# Check Progression on Badges

Tags: support

How can I check progression on badges? E.g. There are badges where they require you do do something 300 times. How do you check how far away from 300 you are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past, I would've used the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). In most cases, someone's already written the query you're looking for. (i.e. [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/249955/epic-legendary-progress-which-days-were-the-ones))

Now, it appears you have this information available to you right in your profile.

1. Go to your profile and select the "Activity" tab in the upper-left.
2. Look in the gray "Badges" block near the top-middle of the page. There's a gear icon that allows you to track the badge of your choice.
3. Click the gear icon to see the progress you're making towards various badges.

[image]

Comment: Thank You, Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Damn that is well hidden

Answer (score 3):

The new profiles we all have includes a new feature that does exactly that. In your own profile, if you go to the settings icon I highlighted here:

[image: Settings]

you can see your major-badge progress.